# how can i get the argument types from a SEL

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, arguments, selector

I have a SEL from a String .I can use "method_copyArgumentType" which is a runtime function to get the type of every argument,like this

```
char *arguType = method_copyArgumentType(m, i);//here m is a Method type,and i is the index of the argument
NSLog(@"method argNum=%d,%s",i,arguType);
```

by this way,if the argument type is a id,it will print"@",but i can't tell what kind of class it is,like a NSArray or a NSDictionary.

Is there a way to get the specific type of the argument?

Comment: Is it possible to get the specific argument type of a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not. The description of a method in a class does not record specific class types for arguments.

Comment: There is `_protocol_getMethodTypeEncoding` ([example](https://gist.github.com/interstateone/2bdcae4dead0f59470a6)). Unfortunately it is a private API, and will result in rejection on App Store submission